# React Material-ui Autocomplete: Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" when clearing the search field

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-state

I want to use an autocomplete field that opens a corresponding modal for the selected item. It works fine, but if I click on the field's 'X' button or just delete the entry using backspace I'm getting the error message that I mentioned.

This is my autocomplete component:

```
 <Autocomplete
        {...defaultProps}
        clearOnEscape
        style={{ width: 400, margin: 'auto' }}
        onChange={(e, value) => handleOpen(value)}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} placeholder='Search for beer...' />
        )}
      />
```

This is the function that deals with the modal (I'm using material ui modal):

```
const handleOpen = value => {
    if (value.id) {
      setIsClicked(beers.find(x => x.id === value.id));
    } else {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems value can be `null` with this component. (According to it's [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) value is a generic type)

You can do

```
if (value && value.id) {}
```

or a defensive return like

```
if (!value) {
    return
}
setIsClicked(beers.find(x => x.id === value.id));
setOpen(true);
```

to be safe